# iOS: Swift: UISlider editingDidEnd not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

[image]

I've set up a function for editing did end with a slider, but it doesn't look like it's being called. I've thrown a print statement into it, and a breakpoint. Is there something else that needs to be done to trigger a function when my user lets go of the slider?

```
    @IBAction func sliderEditingDidEnd(sender: UISlider) {
    print("did end");
}
```

Comment: Show the code of the IBAction

Answer (score 5):

Use the event "Value Changed". If you just want updates for the final value, alter UISlider.continuous

```
var slider = UISlider()
slider.continuous = false
//add slider to view

@IBAction func valueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    println("Value changed.")
}
//prints "Value changed." once upon releasing slider.
```

If the slider needs to be continuous, you can implement an event for UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside.

### [image: Either in storyboard:]

Or in code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mySlider.addTarget(self, action: "userReleasedSlider:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func userReleasedSlider(slider: UISlider) {
    print("User released slider.")
}
```

Comment: I need it to be continuous because I'm using it to control an accessory, and I want to reset it to the middle of the slider when the user lets go of the component.

Comment: Then keep continuous on and create an IBAction for the event "Touch Up Inside." It will run each time the user releases the slider.

Comment: @cweber105 thank you, may I suggest you add the "touch up inside" comment to the answer - it's very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to get the notification when the value is changed. Then you have to set event to 'Value Changed' not 'Editing Did End'.

Comment: No, I want to know when the user has let go of the slider so I can reset it to the middle.

Comment: I don't know what you mean user let go the slider did you mean that when a little bit amount of time past after user release the slider???

Comment: I think you have to use timer to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set both Touch Up Inside and Touch Up Outside to point to your `@IBAction` then you can get the function to fire when the user finishes sliding and keep the slider as continuous.

[image]